# Accidentally changed the permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I've changed the permalink setup on our webpage and now none of the links to the blogs are working. To be honest, I didn't really need to do it, but I was really trying to add a bit more of a description to my url and obviously have done the wrong things.

Is there anyway I can fix this? It just loads the error 401 or it say page not found

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Set yourself up with a local install for testing and playing around purposes. It is quick and easy and there are many tutorials out there covering this. You should never make any changes to a production/live site without testing your changes on a local install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permission for your .htaccess file in your WordPress root and if you are allowed to edit the file then you can just paste the code that you get from setting the permalink structure.

Comment: Thank you for your help Parth, but i can't find where the .htaccess settings are apparently it is supposed to be at the bottom of the permalinks settings page but it doesn't have anything written there, i don't really want to change the permalink i just need the site working again. I have tried to change it back to default but it still doesn't work. It has the custom permalink that i wrote in the custom section..

Comment: Can you please paste the custom permalink structure here for better understanding..

Comment: Sorry mate I'm really really green at this so i appreciate your help 

http://www.seananddanni.com.au/%postname%/ 

This is what i would like to change it to which works fine if i type in the address but if i try and click through the categories menu then find it from the blog page it doesn't open the correct page..

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Parth i ended up re adding the grid that i had created and it fixed it, i appreciate all the help